# systemd-networkd-wait-online failing with SocketCAN interface

Tags: services, systemd-networkd, canbus

I have configured a SocketCAN interface, `can0` (confirmed working using `can-utils`).  I have the below `.network` config file, so that `systemd-networkd` brings up the interface on boot.

```
#/etc/systemd/network/80-can.network
[Match]
Name=can0

[CAN]
BitRate=250K
RestartSec=100ms

[Link]
Unmanaged=no
RequiredForOnline=yes
```

After a bootup, I can see that the interface is up (note `UP` flag set) with either

```
$ ip link show can0
5: can0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 65536
    link/can
```

or

```
$ ifconfig can0
can0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 16
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 65536  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I want to run a oneshot service after `systemd-networkd` brings the network up. Some searching indicates that I should modify the `systemd-networkd-wait-online` service to pass the flag `-i [interface]`, which I've done as

```
$ sudo systemctl edit systemd-networkd-wait-online
#/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online -i can0 --timeout=5
```

In my custom service I use

```
[Unit]
...
After=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
Requires=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

However, the `systemd-networkd-wait-online` fails on boot, and when I run the command in isolation it fails after timing out:

```
$ /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online -i can0 --timeout=5
Event loop failed: Connection timed out
```

For comparison, it succeeds "instantly" when passing `-i eth0`.

So, question(s):

1. Does `systemd-networkd-wait-online` even work with a SocketCAN interface?
2. If it does, what am I doing wrong? or
3. If it doesn't, what would be a functional way to trigger a service at some point after `systemd-networkd` has brought the interface up?

Comment: I'm facing the same exact issue right now. Have you ever found an answer to this?

Comment: @VicenteCunha I'd have to check; I haven't worked on this problem in a few months. In the interim, you may enjoy [this XKCD](https://m.xkcd.com/979/)

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**: the solution below upgrades systemd using a "-backports" suite. This is a critical piece of software, and after I've applied these changes myself, I was no longer able to reboot my device and had to reflash it. Only perform these steps if you know how to fix / recover from any possible consequences of what you're doing!

I believe I found the answer to this. After reading through what I thought to be the relevant systemd source code (https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v241/src/network/networkd-link.c), this appears to be caused by a bug in systemd v241, which is the latest stable release version for the Debian buster suite (Debian 10).

The can links never leave "pending" state in systemd v241. This causes `systemd-networkd-wait-online`, if waiting on a managed can interface to reach "configured" state, to always timeout. To confirm this is indeed the same problem, naturally first check if the version of systemd is 241 (`systemd --version`), then check the `SETUP` state of the can link by running `networkctl`. It will show `pending`, even though the can link is already properly configured and functional.

```
$ networkctl
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged
  2 eth0             ether              routable    configured
  3 eth1             ether              no-carrier  unmanaged
  4 pileft           ether              no-carrier  unmanaged
  5 can0             n/a                carrier     pending
```

The solution I found, if using Debian 10, is to upgrade systemd to v247.3, available from the buster-backports suite. Add this line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
```

Need to add some keys for it:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0E98404D386FA1D9 6ED0E7B82643E131
```

Then upgrade systemd from buster-backports:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install systemd/buster-backports
```

After the upgrade, verify the systemd version has changed to 247 (`systemd --version`), then run `networkctl` again. It should then correctly recognize can link as `configured` (not `pending`):

```
$ networkctl
IDX LINK   TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo     loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 eth0   ether    routable    configured
  3 eth1   ether    no-carrier  unmanaged
  4 pileft ether    no-carrier  unmanaged
  5 can0   can      carrier     configured
```

Then, restarting `systemd-networkd-wait-online` service should no longer give you a timeout error message:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd-wait-online
$ systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-online
● systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Thu 2023-09-07 00:17:41 CEST; 1s ago
   Docs: man:systemd-networkd-wait-online.service(8)
Process: 5824 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 5824 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 07 00:17:41 systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
Sep 07 00:17:41 systemd[1]: Finished Wait for Network to be Configured.
```

Comment: Wow. Good find! Thanks for (most likely) solving my problem! I'll be sure to try this out and intend to accept this answer

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp please be careful if you're going to try this! I don't know if I messed something up, but after attempting to reboot my device after these changes, it's no longer able to boot properly. So don't try this with any crucial device, that you're not willing to reflash later!